# List comprehension AND guards

Tags: erlang, list-comprehension

How to implement `AND` guards in list comprehensions? Separating the guards with comma seems to word as `OR`:

```
1> rd(r, {a, b}).
r
2> L = [#r{a = 1, b =2}, #r{a = 1, b = 3}].
[#r{a = 1,b = 2},#r{a = 1, b = 3}]
3> [X || X <- L, X#r.a =/= 1, X#r.b =/= 2].
[]
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's definitely an AND. The first element fails both tests; the second fails the `X#r.a =/= 1` test.

If you want OR, simply use the `orelse` operator:

```
2> [X || X <- L, X#r.a =/= 1 orelse X#r.b =/= 2].
[#r{a = 1,b = 3}]
```

Comment: Oh, God. Where is my mind? Thanks. What I try to do is include the element if BOTH guards are satisfied.

Comment: @MartinDimitrov: I've amended my answer to cover OR.

Comment: @MartinDimitrov: Glad to. Enjoy your Erlang adventures; it's a fun language to write in.

Comment: Small tip: 'orelse' is in general what you want because it short-circuits the expression which is probably what you would expect. 'or' doesn't do this. [See #9](http://mazenharake.wordpress.com/2010/10/31/9-erlang-pitfalls-you-should-know-about/)

Comment: @MazenHarake: An excellent point! It also helps with precedence.